# Can I include files in a NuGet package, but only when package is installed directly (not as a dependency)?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I want to create a NuGet package that contains files that are added to the project the package is installed to. So far, everything is straightforward.

But then, I want to create a NuGet package from that project as well. And install it to a third project. Is there any way to avoid that the files from the first project are added to that third project?

This is the setup:

**Acme.Doxygen** - "First package" - sets up the target project for doxygen generation

**Acme.MyToolLibrary** - "Second package" - I want to import Acme.Doxygen here, so that this project is documented using Doxygen. Acme.Doxygen adds a file "Doxyfile" to the root of this project.

**Acme.MyWebSite** - "Third package" - I want to install MyToolLibrary in this project, but this project is not interested in Doxygen.

The problem: When I install Acme.MyToolLibrary in Acme.MyWebSite, Doxyfile is added to the root of Acme.MyWebSite. My website is not interested in Doxygen, and I don't want this to happen.

To avoid that Acme.MyWebSite has a dependency on Acme.Doxygen, I have set 'developmentDependency="true"' on the reference to Acme.Doxygen in the packages.config file in Acme.MyToolLibrary. This works fine - Acme.MyWebSite does not depend on Acme.Doxygen. But - how can I configure my NuGet package so that the same logic applies to the Doxyfile included in my NuGet package?